# Is there a way to position different objects above or below each other in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding so I would like to ask if there is an easy way to put certain objects below or above each other in HTML or CSS? If there is can you please explain how? I couldn't find any articles explaining this. [Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZSzn.png)

I'll answer any question to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS includes default styling for the  element itself, as well as separate styles for each of the two images.

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: silver;
  margin-right: 1em;
  object-fit: none;
}

#object-position-1 {
  object-position: 10px;
}

#object-position-2 {
  object-position: 100% 10%;
}
```

```html
<img id="object-position-1" src="mdn.svg" alt="MDN Logo" />
<img id="object-position-2" src="mdn.svg" alt="MDN Logo" />
```

Here we see HTML that includes two  elements, each displaying the MDN logo.

Comment: Can you dumb it down? I'm not used to very complicated stuff yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be that person, but I suggest you watch a few YouTube videos first, it will help you to understand how HTML and CSS work a lot.
Although your question is a bit unclear, from what I understood the thing you're asking for can be done in many ways. For example, flex, grid, absolute positioning and more.

There are many great YouTube channels and website you can learn HTML and CSS from. [Coder Coder](https://www.youtube.com/c/TheCoderCoder) has some great tutorials on her YouTube channel, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) is a website where you can find HTML and CSS related stuff.
Have a look at this Geeks for Geeks [HTML](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html/) and [CSS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css/) tutorial too.

Comment: I think that it's too early for him to deal with grid nor flex templates.
He want just to arrange a few div's AMO.

Comment: @tatactic, That's why I suggested having a look at some HTML and CSS tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

dumber I think, but You have to learn by yourself a little bit!

Take a look at those links :

https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

So, I dumb it down I think...

CSS (style)

```
        body{
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
            font-size:1.2em;
        }
        .above{
            display:relative;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
            padding:20px;
        }
        .above > img{
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align: text-top;
        }
        .middle{
            display:relative;
            background-color:bisque;
            padding:20px;
        }
        .under{
            display:relative;
            background-color:burlywood;
            padding:20px;
        }
```

HTML (body)

```
    <div class="above">
        <img src="../brume.jpg" alt="brume"> I'm above
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        I'm in the middle
    </div>
    <div class="under">
        I'm under
    </div>
```